# R: rvest library to extract nested node content

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

This is a link to a journal page:
https://genomebiology.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13059-018-1535-9 
I'm trying to get the following: Author Affiliations (all authors), Corresponding Author, and Corresponding Author's Email. Note: it is assumed the corresponding author is the last author listed in the authors sections at the top of the article. I've used SelectorGadget to identify some tags for other elements like Abstract and Publication Date, but I just can't seem to figure out how to get these three. The following is my code to get the authors as a character vector:

```
#url is the url for the list of articles on a particular page
s <- html_session(url)<br >
page <- s %>% follow_link(art) %>% read_html()   <br > 
str_replace_all(str_squish(page %>% html_nodes(".AuthorName") %>% html_text()), "[0-9]|Email author", "")<br >
```

And this returns a vector of all authors involved, in this case of length 8 for each of the authors. But now I need to follow the links on their names to get the affiliations, and their emails. I'm sure all the code I need is in  front of me but I'm a little lost as I'm new to R and web scraping (had to learn this  quickly for my current project).

## Update

The answer below is perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure the email address always matches the author at the last position.
Because when I open the Chrome view-source, I find the email address somehow is below an independent list.

```r
library(rvest)
#> 载入需要的程辑包：xml2
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
xml <- read_html('https://genomebiology.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13059-018-1535-9')


xml %>% 
    html_nodes('.EmailAuthor') %>% 
    html_attr('href')
#> [1] "mailto:liuj@cs.uky.edu"
    # get email address

xml %>% 
    html_nodes('.AuthorName') %>% 
    html_text
#> [1] "Ye<U+00A0>Yu"  "Jinpeng<U+00A0>Liu" "Xinan<U+00A0>Liu" "Yi<U+00A0>Zhang"
#> [5] "Eamonn<U+00A0>Magner" "Erik<U+00A0>Lehnert" "Chen<U+00A0>Qian" "Jinze<U+00A0>Liu"
    # get name

data.table(
    name = xml %>% 
        html_nodes('meta') %>% 
        html_attr('name')
    ,content = xml %>% 
        html_nodes('meta') %>% 
        html_attr('content')
) %>% 
    # extract both name and affiliatation, because make show they are matched.
    filter(name %in% c('citation_author_institution')) %>% 
    select(content)
#>                                                                                    content
#> 1                   Department of Computer Science, University of Kentucky, Lexington, USA
#> 2                   Department of Computer Science, University of Kentucky, Lexington, USA
#> 3                   Department of Computer Science, University of Kentucky, Lexington, USA
#> 4                   Department of Computer Science, University of Kentucky, Lexington, USA
#> 5                   Department of Computer Science, University of Kentucky, Lexington, USA
#> 6                                               Seven Bridges Genomics Inc, Cambridge, USA
#> 7 Department of Computer Engineering, University of California Santa Cruz, Santa Cruz, USA
#> 8                   Department of Computer Science, University of Kentucky, Lexington, USA
```

<sup>Created on 2018-11-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much this is very helpful and clears it up a little but. I am still having trouble extracting the "affiliated with" content. This is retrieved when you click on the author, i.e. Hua Ying, and it says Division of Ecology and Evolution, Research School of Biology, Australian National University, Acton, ACT, 2601, Australia. Other authors have more than one affiliations.

Comment: I tried to parse by xpath, your answer is very fast and efficient. May I know how do you know use `.EmailAuthor` and `.AuthorNames`?

`xml %>% 
    html_nodes('.u-listReset') %>% 
    html_text(trim=TRUE) %>% 
    str_split(', |and|[0-9]{1}') %>% 
    unlist %>% 
    str_trim %>% 
    .[nchar(.) > 0] %>% 
    .[-length(.)]`

Comment: @RYOENGLianHu you can use SelectorGadget to select the CSS tag instead of the XPath as per https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n4w8RLCtf7c

Comment: To get the affiliation ID I did `xml %>% %>% html_nodes(".AffiliationID")` and this gave me the IDs for the affiliations, but extracting the text is tricky

Comment: @RYOENGLianHu I just use Chrome view source function. I assume your environment is Win. Just `Ctrl+U` and `Ctrl+F` what you want.

Comment: @Connor Watson I got your point. I am still working on it, when I finish it and I will let you know.

Comment: @Connor Watson, I update my answer with affiliations.

Comment: @Jiaxiang Ahh thank you so much! Your answer is very concise and helpful. It seems like you have a deep understanding of CSS/XML structure, and because I don't I could not understand how to get this solution. For example I have to research more "meta" + "name" and "meta" + "content".

Comment: @ConnorWatson Hi, I think there is a quick way. You know what data you want. Just open Chrome view source and ctrl+f it, you will find it. There are two kinds of information I think it is important. One is the `class` which is inside the HTML tag language. It leads you to type something in the function `html_nodes`. The other is the attributes like href (URL) or something. It leads you to type something in the function `html_attr`. I think the two functions in the `rvest` package is enough to do this job. SelectorGadget is helpful but it is not a good tool when you want to go deeper.